# Syncing page numbering in PDF and in the page indicator

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm looking at a PDF file I have. (A textbook from my prof. in PDF version).

When I'm on page "vii" in the textbook, then every PDF Viewer software will  tell me that I'm on page 7.

Is it possible to use Adobe Acrobat such that these two things a consistent with each other?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This doesn't appear to be a graphic design question. Perhaps this question would be more suitable for SuperUser.

Comment: @BillyKerr  you are probably right. Can I move this to superuser?

Comment: Yes. You can flag your own question and ask a mod to migrate it for you.